# Apply function with destPoint function

Tags: r, geometry, apply

I would like to apply the destPoint function over my dataframe but I am struggling to get it to work.

I have the following code working correctly so I am falling down when applying it over my dataframe:

```
sectorCoor <- as.vector(t(destPoint(c(-8.609117,52.69373),c(360,9.6,19.8,30,40.2,50.4,60.6),2500)))
```

The transpose and as vector as purely cosmetic so that I have a single line of values for each row of my dataframe.

where -8.609117,52.69373 are the origin lat longs (col H&I in my sample file),
      360,9.6,19.8,30,40.2,50.4,60.6 (col AQ-AW) are the bearings I wish to calculate the endpoint for and 2500 is the distance I wish to calculate over.

When I try to incorporate the apply function using the code below I get errors:

```
siteCoor <- apply(RNC20[,c(7:8,42:48)],1, function(x) destPoint(c(x[1]:x[2]),c(x[3]:x[9]),2500)) 

Error in .pointsToMatrix(p) : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2
```

I believe the p refers to the p variable in destPoint which is the long lat input which can be a vector of two numbers or a matrix of two columns. In my code above I have referenced these two inputs as a vector `c(x[1]:x[2])`, can someone correct me on the error here?

I have some sample data [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15dQMW8yYj-oVNFbKrjn89gvqr5BjKqqmuB0A1ET4R0M/pub?output=csv) if it helps

As a secondary problem how can I change the distance element (2500 at the end) in the equation to be based on the contents of column J? If J = 10564 set the distance to 2500, if J = 10589 distance = 2200, if J = 10613 set distance = 1900 and if J = 3088 set the distance = 3000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not `x[1]:x[2]` but `x[1:2]`. And it is vectorized, so you needn't use `c()`.

```
apply(RNC20[,c(7:8,42:48)],1, function(x) destPoint(x[1:2], x[3:9], 2500))
```

I can't understand how to get distance values from J. Are J some kind of ID? If so, I think it is a steady method to add distance `column`. If not (or you want to solve it using function), it woud be good idea to make `function()` that take J as an argument and output distance.

for example:

```
JtoDist <- function(x) x^2
apply(RNC20[,c(7:8,42:48, JcolNum)] function(x) destpoint(x[1:2], x[3:9], JtoDist(x[10])))
```

**[EDITED]**

```
library(geosphere)
RNC20 <- read.csv("RNC.csv")[,-1]

# Maybe this is what you want ?
t(apply(RNC20[,c(7:8,42:48)],1, function(x) t(destPoint(x[1:2], x[3:9], 2500))))

# or here ? (long format)
library(reshape2)
res <- apply(RNC20[,c(7:8,42:48)],1, function(x) destPoint(x[1:2], x[3:9], 2500))
colnames(res) <- RNC20[,"Cell.Reference"]
rownames(res) <- rep(colnames(RNC20[,42:48]), 2)
melt.res <- cbind(melt(res[1:7,], value.name = "Longitude"), melt(res[8:14,], value.name = "Latitude"))[, c(2,1,3,6)]
head(melt.res)

# question2: an functional approach
J <- c(10564,10589, 10613, 3088)
set.seed(1); RNC20_J <- cbind(RNC20, J = sample(J, 18, replace = T))

JtoDist <- function(x) switch( which(c(x==10564, x==10589, x== 0613, x==3088)), 2500, 2200, 1900, 3000)
JtoDist(10589)    # [1] 2200

t(apply(RNC20_J[,c(7:8,42:49)], 1, function(x) t(destPoint(x[1:2], x[3:9], JtoDist(x[10])))))
```

Comment: Thanks cuttlefish44, yeah column J is an ID, it identifies higher and lower frequencies, the higher the frequency the smaller the distance. Sorry I'm not catching the JtoDist function above, do I need to define 4 functions given there's 4 unique values in column J?

Comment: Given my original RNC20 data has 3122 observation and now siteCoor had 43708 elements meaning there's 14 'entries' per observation i.e. 1 Lat and 1 Long * 7, how can I pair these Lat and Longs together?

Comment: When I transpose it I get the values by row but the Lat Long pairs are mixed  up
`1
-8.609505
-8.602948
-8.596586
-8.590621
-8.585241
-8.580617
-8.576895
52.71620
52.71588
52.71487
52.71319
52.71089
52.70805
52.70476
2
-8.590303
-8.596234
-8.602573
-8.609117
-8.615662
-8.622000
-8.627931
52.67439
52.67268
52.67162
52.67127
52.67162
52.67268
52.67439
3
-8.644000
-8.641276
-8.637535
-8.632894
-8.627501
-8.621527
-8.615159
52.70119
52.70483
52.70811
52.71094
52.71323
52.71490
52.71590`

Comment: Notice how all the Latitudes are paired together and similarly the Longitudes. Ideally for each row I could get the corresponding lat and long together i.e -8.609505 52.71620, -8.602948 52.71588......

Comment: By the way I have taken your advice and added another column to the original file with the distance and that aspect works perfectly now. Many thanks